# Understanding MIDI text files fields and form

Tags: midi

I am trying to understand the midi text files.
I did two conversions using the site [midi to txt converter](http://flashmusicgames.com/midi/mid2txt.php), converting a drums only sample and a full midi song.

- **The site gives you two possible formats, raw and delta. What is the
  difference between them ?**

I attach two images, one is the drum track comparing raw and delta , the other is the full song comparing raw and delta.

- I named the columns 1 - 5 the raw and 1d - 5d the delta. I see the
  first column changing only. **What is column 1 and column 1d ?**
- My guesses for the rest of the columns, ch should be differents
  instrument, v velocity and c midi channel mapping (the tone)?
- **The tempo stamp at the beginning of the file is counted in what units?**
- At the full song, before the columns, is some incomprehensible stuff (red box)**, what is that ?**
- Column 2, on drum track is on/off, on the full song its Par/PrCh . Whats that and why is it different?

A link to a complete guide would be helpful also,

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to get ahold of the software author and ask him.  But I've written some midi software - I'll take a crack at it...

> The site gives you two possible formats, raw and delta. What is the difference between them ?

don't use delta - that's the time straight from the midi file (additional time since last event).  Raw is in song ticks.  Find 2 notes that are a measure apart to see how many ticks per measure.  Divide by 4 to get a quarter note, etc.

ch will be the midi channel.  n is the note (60=middle C probably).  v is velocity (between 1 - 127 for note on)

I don't see a 'c' column ??

tempo is in microseconds per quarter note (usually displayed in less precise quarter note per minute)

stuff in the red box are system exclusive events.  a bunch of binary that only one particular synth understands.  if it came from a roland, a yamaha won't understand it.  Another model of roland MIGHT, but might not.  Usually stores exact sounds, etc.

The Par stuff is a control change event (control change on channel 9 on control 64 (hold pedal) to value 64 (hold down)

I'm guessing ParCh is system common midi events starting with hex $Fx.

In any case, I'd recommend not using that utility.  I doubt it will work for all midi files you come across.
Here's where I learned about midi.
http://midi.teragonaudio.com/

It's a pretty steep learning curve, but VERY fun.